# Merging every 4 rows together but with repeating "ids"

Tags: pandas, group-by

Hey all I have this following pandas dataframe

I did not manage to paste the column names in here but here they are:
`['Index', 'Subject', 'In set (l)', 'Choice', 'Accuracy', 'Response Time', 'showd_word']`

```
0      1   191251      False    NaN       NaN            NaN        NaN
1      2   191251        NaN      s       NaN            NaN        NaN
2      3   191251        NaN    NaN       1.0            NaN        NaN
3      4   191251        NaN    NaN       NaN         1770.2        NaN
4      5   191251       True    NaN       NaN            NaN        NaN
5      6   191251        NaN      s       NaN            NaN        NaN
6      7   191251        NaN    NaN       0.0            NaN        NaN
7      8   191251        NaN    NaN       NaN          872.2        NaN
8      9   191251       True    NaN       NaN            NaN        NaN
9     10   191251        NaN      l       NaN            NaN        NaN
```

As you can see, every subject has a lot of entries (50 to be exact), scattered over many rows. I would like to add every 4 rows (so index 0, 1, 2 and 3) to one row. Then, I would like to have index 4, 5, 6 and 7 on the next row.

I have tried to do this using groupby and set_index, but I did not manage, partly (I think) because grouping by the 'Subject' is hard since there are many rows with the same subject.

Is there a clever way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the below approach doesn't fully work, please provide an example of your data with more Subjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to [`groupby.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) using a range grouper:

```
N = 4
out = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//N).first()
```

If you have another grouper (like Subject):

```
out = df.groupby(['Subject', np.arange(len(df))//N], as_index=False).first()
```

output:

```
   Index  Subject  In set (l) Choice  Accuracy  Response Time  showd_word
0      1   191251       False      s       1.0         1770.2         NaN
1      5   191251        True      s       0.0          872.2         NaN
2      9   191251        True      l       NaN            NaN         NaN
```

If you want to try to determine N automatically, you can take the columns and get the most frequent length of the non-NA+NAs stretches. This won't be fail-proof and might be tweaking but this works in the current example:

```
def find_N(s):
    m = s.notna()
    if m.any():
        return s.groupby(m.cumsum()).size().mode()[0]
    return -1

N = df.apply(find_N).max()
# 4
```

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to answer! I have figured it all out now!! Thanks!